Is there any way at all to get the size of a dynamic array with sizeof()?
I'm a computer science student and one of the questions on a test asked to implement realloc in C using malloc. My teacher said the correct answer would be to get the sizeof of the previous array and compare to the new size before copying the elements of the previous array.
I asked him if the sizeof function could actually do that and he said it could but I couldn't find it anywhere. Sorry if this is a duplicate or similar to another question but I need to be sure.

No, you can't get sizeof of malloc-allocated array. You could get it in some cases from the metadata of the allocated block, but it is implementation specific.

Nitpicking: sizeof is an operator not a function. It's no different from e.g. the pointer-to operator & (well, except its behavior). The confusion usually comes from the need to use parentheses for type-names (like sizeof(int)), but they are not needed for general expressions (like sizeof my_int_variable).

@pmg If the ask is to re-implement realloc in isolation, then it is virtually impossible without getting into the specific implementation internals.

As for the problem if creating a realloc-like function, unless you also have control of the malloc function it's not possible. You either need to create your own memory-management system, know the exact details of the current memory management system used by your specific implementation of malloc, or otherwise it's not possible.

It is not possible to implement realloc without also implementing malloc, calloc and free --- unless you are tied to one implementation of malloc and can use its internal workings (which you will need to discover through documentation, source code, or if all else fails, experimentation).

If this is really a question in exam, and it requires to re-implement realloc stand-alone, then I'd question the teacher's competence.

Thank you all for the answers. I asked my teacher how to get the size of the array exactly and he deflected saying he didn't want us to write functional code, but to try to handle possible errors, including errors caused by a difference in size between the previous array and the new array. So, I was wrong because I didn't code something I knew wouldn't work.

Your teacher is wrong on this.
Most uses of sizeof are evaluated only at compile-time (the exception is VLAs, which malloc doesn't deal with). As such, sizeof does not work on malloc'ed memory that is allocated at runtime.
You would need to implement malloc and store the allocated size as a hidden field inside the memory block itself in order for your realloc to be able to query it later.
